# Dividing a triangle into seventeen equal parts.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles, pigeonhole-principle

I was trying to solve a problem on Pigeonhole principle from Problem Solving Strategies by Arthur Engel.

> A target has the form of an equilateral triangle with side 2 units.
>
> 1. If it is hit $5$ times, then there will be two holes with distance $\le 1$.
> 2. If it is hit $17$ times. What is the minimal distance of two holes at most?

---

I was able to solve $1$. Here is what I did.

Divide the triangle into four equal parts, each of them an equilateral triangle of length $1$ as shown in the figure.

[image: Divide triangle into four equal parts]

Now using pigeonhole principle, there exists at least $2$ points that lie in or on the boundary of the same triangle. It is clear that the distance between then shall be $\le 1 \qquad \square$

I think that the same reasoning can be applied to problem $2$ and all I have to do is to divide the triangle into $17$ equal parts. How can I achieve that?

---

EDIT: I made a mistake with $17$, the triangle needs to be divided into $16$ equal parts to solve the problem. For $16$ equal parts, we can continue the process by which we divided the larger triangle into $4$ to the smaller triangles. That leaves answer $\le \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Why seventeen? There is a trivial way to divide an equilateral triangle in sixteen ($4\times 4$) equilateral triangles, hence with $17$ hits there are two arrows whose distance is $\leq\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why $17$ equal part? In (i) you divide triangle into $4=5-1$ parts. Do the same with $16=17-1$ parts (it's easy - divide each side into $4$ parts).

Answer (score 0):

Here you split 1 big triangle into 4 equal smaller triangles. If you treat the smaller triangles the same way as you did the big triangle, each of the smaller triangles gets divided into 4 further smaller equal triangles (which gives the answer of 1/2).

[image]